# Alternative Options: onmousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, svg

An issue in the Chrome browser (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=170631) is causing quite a few issues with functionality that I'm building for a website at the moment.  In the application if an onmousemove event is triggered simultaneously as a onmousedown event it appends a class that disables accidental link following since the user is dragging DOM elements. However, if an onmousedown event is fired and there is no movement (essentially a single click) it will follow the link.

This works flawlessly on everything except Chrome, since it incorrectly interprets an onmousedown event as an onmousemove event (occurs with both JavaScript & jQuery).  I thought about adding a timer to determine how long the user has held the mouse button down to distinguish the difference between click and drag, but this seems like an inefficient and potentially error prone option.  Any thoughts on how I could setup a work around until Chrome fixes this bug would be much appreciated.

Comment: The problem seems to be more with the fact that the textarea has a scrollbar that autoscrolls to the latest position rather than the mouse directly. The box scrolls making it appear that the mouse moved. Provide us a code example of your exact problem and perhaps womeone can come up with a work around. Try disabling the scroll in their example to see what I mean, http://jsfiddle.net/numre/7/

Comment: The box was just an example someone specifically setup to easily demonstrate the bug, but it will occur without one as well.  Unfortunately I can't post all of the code online, but I'm using dom-drag.js by youngpup for the dragging functionality.  I've settled on using a window.setTimeout as a fix in the interim. When it detects on onmousedown it sets moveTimeout = window.setTimeout('disableLinks()', 150); and then clears the timeout and removes the class when an onmouseup event fires.  It's not the most elegant solution, but it appears to be the best option at this point in time.